# How to create links based on the node's in-degree?

Tags: netlogo

I am having some difficulties to create links from two different breeds, humans and zombies. 
These links should be created in such a way that turtles from the first breed (humans) with more links (in-degree) have a higher probability of linking the second breeds (zombies) - i.e.,the probability of a turtle from the humans being selected is proportional to the node's `in-degree k_in`.
At each tick, I add a zombie in the network.

By considering the preferential attachment model, I wrote:

```
 let thisZombie one-of [both-ends] of one-of links 
          create-link-with thisZombie
```

but it has returned me the following error:

```
LINKS is a directed breed.
error while zombie 10 running CREATE-LINK-WITH
  called by procedure ADD-ZOMBIE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'.
```

This is the whole code for this part:

```
create-zombies 1
   [

    if targeting = "first model"
    [
     let thisZombie self
     ask one-of humans
      [
        ifelse random-float 1 < p
         [create-link-from thisZombie [set color red]]
         [ask thisZombie [die]]
      ]
    ]

    if targeting = "second model (preferential_attachment)"
    [
      let thisZombie one-of [both-ends] of one-of links 
      create-link-with thisZombie
    ]
  ]
```

I have the two following questions:

1. How can I select the human based on its `in-degree`?
2. Is it correct to use `create-link-with one-of both-ends` in case of two different breeds?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct general approach (which I suppose you've lifted from the **Preferential Attachment** model in the NetLogo Models Library) but there are two things that are causing you problems:

- You correctly using `one-of links` to pick a link, but by then picking `one-of [both-ends]` of that link, you could be picking *either* the human *or* the zombie, which is not what you want. If your links are always from a zombie to a human (like they seem to be based on the code for your `"first model"`, then the human will always be `end2` of the link, you can write: `[end2] of one-of links`. If you didn't know the direction of the link, you could write `[one-of both-ends with [breed = humans]] of one-of links`, but that would be less efficient.
- You cannot mix directed and undirected "unbreeded" links. (See [the user manual](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links) for more details on this.)

Supposing, again, that your links are always from zombie to human, your code should look something like this:

```
if targeting = "second model (preferential_attachment)" [
  let thisZombie self
  ; pick the human end of a random link
  ask [end2] of one-of links [ create-link-from thisZombie ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nicolas. You answer is so clear and I understood better how the links works in case of preferential attachment. May I ask you if in this way I am taking into account a selection of humans based on their in-degree?

Comment: Yes. You can think of each link as a "lottery ticket": the higher your in-degree, the more lottery tickets you have, so selection is proportional to in-degree. Another way to do the same thing would be to use [`rnd` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html), which should give you the same result (but a be bit slower).